# How do I add a string to an array through a button and then set it on the page?

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my current code, I'm just getting started with javascript.

```
<script>
  var array = ["Volvo", "BMW", "Range Rover"];
  document.write(array);
</script>

Ferrari is not added in you car collection, want to add it? 
<button class="" onclick=""> Add car </button>
```

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Try and edit your question to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var array = ["Volvo", "BMW", "Range Rover"];
      document.write(array);
    </script>

    <button class="" onclick="javascript:array.push('Ferrari');document.write(array);"> Add car </button>

  </body>
</html>
```